# Call to undefined method Directory ::getHeaderInfo() in php

Tags: php, ldap, lamp

I have defined a class called Directory.php

```
    class Directory{
      public function getHeaderInfo($ID){

        $ldap = connect() or die("Unable to connect to server");
     }
    }
```

I have then called the class inside of `StartPage.php`:

```
 $directory = new Directory();
 $directory->getHeaderInfo($ID);
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Call to undefined method getHeaderInfo()
```

What have I done wrong? Is it a function scope in PHP as the class exists without the `require` or include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are trying to redeclare internal PHP class called Directory

http://php.net/manual/en/class.directory.php

try to change class name

2. include file Directory.php

Comment: i used include_once('DirectoryAccess.php'); but i get DirectoryAccess' not found

Comment: you wrote: I have defined a class called Directory.php
and you try include file  DirectoryAccess.php. What is the filename?

Comment: yeh i fixed that now, just a connectivity issue now though thanks